# Threads are the bane of my existence

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, delegates

I have a button which on click will run a Sub, creating a process which runs a script.
When this script is finished an Exited handler will fire and run another Sub which cleans up so that the application is ready to go anew without restarting it.

I disable the button during the run and try to re-enable it when the Exit is fired, however it tells me that the button is in another thread. So I tried using SynchronizedContext and Post:

Declared at the start of my class:

```
Class MainWindow
    Private sc As SynchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current
```

Not sure if I'm doing that correctly but it worked for me elsewhere in the code where I had the same problem.
The exit handling sub:

```
Private Sub CMD_Exited(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    myProcess.CancelOutputRead()
    myProcess.CancelErrorRead()
    sc.Post(AddressOf Button_Click, Button1.IsEnabled = True)
    Close()
End Sub
```

Which errors:

> *Method 'Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)' does not have a signature compatible with delegate 'Delegate Sub SendOrPostCallback(state As Object)'.*

What can I do here? Changing the button signature will cause incompatibilities elsewhere.

Are there better ways to get around this threads issue?

Comment: The error is pretty clear: you're trying to make `Button_Click` a `SendOrPostCallback` method, but the signature doesn't match the delegate definition. You haven't even shown us the code involved with the error, the delegate declaration, how you're wiring up the event, or anything relevant to the issue you're having. You can't wire up `Button_Click` to something that wants a `SendOrPostCallback`, because the signatures don't match. You could *make* the signatures match by moving the `state` into an `EventArgs` object, perhaps.

Comment: FWIW the problem has much more to do with understanding delegates than threading.

Comment: What you need is to invoke on the UI thread. See [**this documentation example**](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vb.net/1913/threading/6235/performing-thread-safe-calls-using-control-invoke#t=201703151444197178679) of mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Visual Vincent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3740093/visual-vincent) is correct, you need to invoke on the UI thread.  Specifically you need to read this [How to: Make Thread-Safe Calls to Windows Forms Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
Public Delegate Sub DoProcessStuffOnUIThreadHandler()

Private Sub CMD_Exited(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If Me.Button1.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New DoProcessStuffOnUIThreadHandler(AddressOf DoProcessStuffOnUIThread)
        Me.Button1.Invoke(d)
    Else
        DoProcessStuffOnUIThread()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub DoProcessStuffOnUIThread()
    myProcess.CancelOutputRead()
    myProcess.CancelErrorRead()
    Button1.IsEnabled = True
    Close()
End Sub
```

(28-SEP-2017) Edit to add an alternative, that I used frequently in my WinForms code days, for brevity:

```
Public Delegate Sub DoProcessStuffOnUIThreadHandler()

Private Sub CMD_Exited(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If Me.Button1.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New DoProcessStuffOnUIThreadHandler(AddressOf CMD_Exited)
        Me.Button1.Invoke(d)
    Else
        myProcess.CancelOutputRead()
        myProcess.CancelErrorRead()
        Button1.IsEnabled = True
        Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

The added example simply reduces code use.  Both examples end in the same result.  Hope that helps.